# "Include Site Name in Page Titles" not work at all

Tags: php, joomla3.3

I have a Joomla website and set "Site Name" correctly and set "Include Site Name in Page Titles
No" on After or Before. You can check the my global configuration in the screenshots.

I have the same configuration in another website and it's working fine, but on this website, I have the title in back-end only and in the front-end, it just shows menu Name like "Home".

I have a custom template installed on this website, then if the issue may be because of that please advise.

[image: My Global Configuration]

Please assist me if you have any idea about this issue or solution.
Thanks.

Comment: May be related to your theme. But this is off topic ! We help you about coding purpose. In your case your problem is software related.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But that is the point. I have a custom template and want to know if the issue is related to the template, then I can fix it as well.

Comment: How would we know anything about your custom template? If you want us to help you fix the code, you should include the relevant portion (whatever part is supposed to display the site name in the titles).

Comment: Please try to set the default template `protostar` and if the problem is getting fixed, it's a problem with your custom template.